# When posting a text field which contains http link in its value error ocurs

Tags: php, forms, http

I have a form on my web page and on button click i try go post some variables in one of which i hold in its value a http://somelink.com and when the post occurs i get server error, if i take off http:// from the value of the text field everything goes ok.Has anyone any idea what should be this issue? Thank you in

here is part of my form

```
<form method="post" action="./edit.php" name="one" id="one">
 Name: <input type="text" name="BanName" id="BanName" value=""/><br/>
 Link: <input type="text" name="Link" id="Link" value=""/><br/>
 <input type="button" id="but" name="but" value="Submit"  onClick="document.one.submit();" />
</form>
```

here is what i get

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /b/admin/edit.php on this server.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

PHP Version 5.3.27

After i get the variable with $_POST["Link"] i call this function

```
 function generateIframeBanner($src){
if(!preg_match('/^http:\/\//',$src)){
    $src='http://'.$src;
}
$html='<iframe src="'.$src.'" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
return $html;   
   }
```

Comment: The problem is probably in your PHP, since forms don't care what's in the values when they submit. But since you haven't shown your PHP code, we can't tell what you've done wrong.

Comment: Ok, you added a few details of the error you get. This clearly shows that the problem lies in what you do with the content. There is nothing we can say to this, since we do not know your code.

Comment: at least post the javascript function you're using there.

Comment: i dont use any javascript function in this part of the code

Comment: can you show how you are calling `generateIframeBanner`?

Comment: $bannerIframeSrc=$_POST['bannerIframeSrc'];
 if ($bannerIframeSrc!="")
    echo generateIframeBanner($bannerIframeSrc);